# Angular Ui-Grid enableHiding does not work

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I cannot disable colum Hiding
var gridOptions = { enableHiding: false,

This should be simple thing. But why I cannot make it work?
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/303_customizing_column_menu

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to place the `enableHiding` flag into the `columnDefs` for all respective columns. Putting it into gridOptions does not seem to work.

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mdQFySWpfcKEw4zyoTbU?p=preview).